# How to stop bzr from using ssh (asking a password) for downloading?

Tags: ssh, application-development, password, launchpad, bazaar

I have configured bzr to push updates and now it's using ssh for downloading all the branches too. Is it possible to use ssh only for uploading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use different branch URLs for push and pull. First check the current related branches with `bzr info`:

```
$ bzr info
Standalone tree (format: 2a)
Location:
  branch root: .

Related branches:
    push branch: bzr+ssh://somehost.example.org/home/user/foo/
  parent branch: bzr+ssh://somehost.example.org/home/user/foo/
```

To switch any of these, just issue the push or pull command with the `--remember` option, such as:

```
$ bzr pull --remember http://somehost.example.org/~user/foo/
```

After that, you can verify the new setting with `bzr info` again.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a public key for password-less SSH logins?

Fast instructions:

1. Generate a new key-pair:

   $ ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. Copy you public key the SSH server:

   $ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub YourUserName@SSH-Server-Host

[Permanent ssh-add keys with password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138892/permanent-ssh-add-keys-with-password)

Comment: it is a passphrase request for the key, actually

Comment: I have linked a question of mine to permanent store keys with password

Comment: I don't see how this answer is related to the question.

Comment: @Raim This is how you set up ssh to grab the files using an ssh key instead of a password.  When Bazaar is configured to go over ssh this eliminates the prompt for the ssh password.